# File Conversion on server side using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, html, video, ffmpeg

The conversion of file from any format to mp4, following are some of the preferred  formats
file formats `flv,webm,wmv,avi,m4v` are the files which i am using, and i tried many of the codec with different `ffmpeg` `linux` version but failed. please do the needful help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem and what you want to do. Can you add more informations ?

Comment: i need linux commands for converting files to mp4 format on linux server . For the above mentioned format files

Comment: Then you must be more specific what you tried. Which ffmpeg version and which distribution do you use?

Comment: The latest ffmpeg version from http://ffmpeg.org/ is being downloaded and installed , but any of the commands doesnt work.

Comment: What is the output of the console once you have launched the command ?

Comment: FFmpeg version SVN-r15137, Copyright (c) 2000-2008 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration:
  libavutil     49.10. 0 / 49.10. 0
  libavcodec    51.70. 0 / 51.70. 0
  libavformat   52.21. 0 / 52.21. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  built on Aug 31 2008 21:44:56, gcc: 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)

Comment: Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 25.00 (25/1)
Input #0, flv, from '166_lesson.flv':
  Duration: 00:00:40.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 160 kb/s   this is the logged error  
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 308x231, 25.00 tb(r)
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 160 kb/s
WARNING: The bitrate parameter is set too low. It takes bits/s as argument, not kbits/s
ffmpeg: unrecognized option '-c:a'

Comment: This version is quite old (2008). Have you tried newer versions?

Answer (score 1):

To convert a video file with [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) from one format to another, you usually just use

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv video.mp4
```

with the appropriate file extension.

If this doesn't work and you use Debian or Ubuntu, this might be due to Debian not using the original `ffmpeg`. See [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) for some details.

*Update:*

From the comments to your question, it seems that you have downloaded the current version from http://ffmpeg.org/. But the version used is `SVN-r15137` from 2008 (built on Aug 31 2008). Maybe the build or the installation failed.

If the installation worked, look where the ffmpeg executable is and try the commands you posted with a full path, e.g.

```
/path/to/bin/ffmpeg -y -i input.flv -strict -2 -ar ... output.mp4
```

and so on.

If this succeeds, you must either use the full path to the ffmpeg binary or add the binary path to the `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: i downloaded the latest ffmpeg from the site mentioned and executed the code, but didn't work for me please help out

Comment: What is your error ? Because what Olaf told you is correct. If you just say "it doesn't work", don't expect help from us because it is just not possible. Add logs to your comment.

Comment: these are the commands which iam using ffmpeg -y -i "+ input.flv + " -strict -2 -ar 22050 -ab 512 -b 800k -f mp4 -s 514:362 -c:a aac -b:a 128k "+ output +".mp4";
   
      ffmpeg -i "  input.webm " "+ output +".mp4";
   
      ffmpeg -i " input.avi + " -ar 22050 -ab 32 -s 514:362 " + output +".mp4";
   
      ffmpeg -i " +input.wmv + " -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast " + output +".mp4";